# SQL Oracle query. Which customer name and number ordered the highest priced item in October?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

Which customer name and number ordered the highest priced item in October?

```
Customer name = account_name [found in table cust_accounts]
customer number = account_number [found in table cust_accounts]
price = unit_selling_price [found in table order_lines_all]
date = creation_date [found in table order_lines_all]
```

Here is what I have:

```
select account_name, account_number, max(unit_selling_price)
from cust_accounts ca, order_lines_all ola 
where trunc(ola.creation_date) between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-30'
```

I have no idea what to group or order by. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a group by:

```
    select ca.account_name, ca.account_number, ola.max(unit_selling_price) as MaxPrice
    from cust_accounts ca, order_lines_all ola 
    where trunc(ola.creation_date) between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-30'
and ca.account_number = ola.account_number
    group by account_name, account_number
```

The MaxPrice will group automatically.  You need to manually add the other 2.
But even there, you may end up with more records than you expect, if the account_name can have more than one account_number.

(I added in a simple way to join without making it complicated.  But it only assumes that that field exists in both places.  You have to join it on something.)

Comment: you would get a `cross join`ed result.

Comment: Yeah, well, he didn't specify how it was joined.

Comment: I cannot use ca.account_number = ola.account_number because there is not an account number in the line level. There is nothing similar in those two tables.

Comment: How are you able to tell what sales were made then?  You have to join something?  You may need to modify that table to add a key for the JOIN.

Comment: @applesandgrapes itll be useful to post the table details. how can you identify in the order_lines_all table which customer purchased this and that if there is no account number in that table?